# html5 video choppy and slow

Tags: javascript, html, performance, video

when browsing my homepage www.sequent.at at work it is really fast and you it actually works as designed(we have fast internet here). at home or at other computers it is really choppy.. althought i added events like canplaythrough

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" loop="true" autobuffer>
    <source src="video/Higrukurz.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2">
    <source src="video/Higrukurz.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/Higrukurz.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="video/Higrukurz.swf" id="video_background">
        <param name="movie" value="video/Schneemed.swf" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="scale" value="exactfit" /> 
    </object>
</video>
<script>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('video_background').load();
document.getElementById('video_background').addEventListener("canplaythrough", function()
  {
    document.getElementById('video_background').play();
  }
);
```

my question is what can possibly slow it down so heavy ? i cant imagine that the client machines are the whole problem(internet speed, browser)

actually there is only the mp4 file on the server so dont mind if firebug, etc. says "missing video"

Comment: Hey newbie : )  I probably can't - but a link would definitely help test/debugging..

Comment: i posted the link in the first sentence :) but here you go with a hyperlink [link](http://www.sequent.at)

Comment: Not choppy at all here (Chrome + Firefox). Looks great - very evocative landing page!

Comment: the problem might be pushing a 1080p video down to some users, especially if they don't need that large a frame size. encoding mostly looks good, already getting some artifacts so probably don't want more compression. try smaller frame size and a two pass encode